# Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Не могу подключить firebase выбивает ошибку при синхронизации - Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.anton1111.azot2.antonio_chat"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

        //firebase libs
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'



        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В случае, если вы попытались добавить сервисы `Firebase` через инструменты, то в Android Studio (версии 3.1.2 и выше) существует баг, согласно которому некорректно добавляются библиотеки Firebase.

Например:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

Вместо:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

В вашем модуле Gradle уже существует данная библиотека и вы пытаетесь добавить её снова.

Также, согласно [замечаниям](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_june_12_2018) к документации `Firebase` от 12 Июня 2018 года для корректного использования сервисов вам необходимо добавить библиотеку `Firebase Core`, которая у вас отсутствует.

Comment: Удаляю 15.0.0 затем нажимаю try again после этого ошибка исчезает но как только нажимаю "Add Firebase Authentication to your app" снова появляется эта ошибка

Comment: @Anton если нажимаешь try again и ошибка исчезает, вероятно библиотека уже добавилась. Зачем пытаться её добавить снова?

Comment: Firebase Authentication к приложению не подключается